# Buffer bounded problem using semaphores using C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, mutex, semaphore, producer-consumer

I need help with my assignment. The assignment is about there is one producer and argv[1] number of consumers. Producer will produce a number from 1001 to 1010 and consumer will consume it. Everything is fine with the output of my code but the main issue is my code is not terminating. Can anyone help me with it.**HELP IS NEEDED!!** This is my code:-`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define MAXIMUM 5
#define lower_time 2
#define max_time 5

void *producer();
void *consumer();

sem_t empty;
sem_t full;
int in = 0;
int out = 0;
int buffer[MAXIMUM];
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  /* argv[1] is number of consumer thread*/

  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int a[n];

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    a[i]=(i+1);
  }

  for(int i=0;i<MAXIMUM;i++) {
    buffer[i]=0;
  }

  pthread_t ptid;
  pthread_t ctid[n];

  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
  sem_init(&empty,0,MAXIMUM);
  sem_init(&full,0,0);

  printf("NUmber of consumer thread :- %d\n",n);
  printf("Number of producer thread will be 1\n");

  int in = 0; //index at which producer will put the next data
  int out = 0; // index from which the consumer will consume next data

  //creation of producer thread
  pthread_create(&ptid,NULL,(void*)producer,NULL);

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    pthread_create(&ctid[i],NULL,(void*)consumer,(void*)&a[i]);
  }

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
     pthread_join(ctid[i],NULL);
  }

  pthread_join(ptid,NULL);

  sem_destroy(&empty);
  sem_destroy(&full);

  sleep(n);

  exit(0);
}

void insert_item(int item) {
  sem_wait(&empty);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  buffer[in] = item;
  printf("Producer is writing :- Insert Item %d at %d\n",buffer[in],in);
  printf("Buffer Contents:-");
  for(int i=0;i<MAXIMUM;i++) {
    printf("%d  ",buffer[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  in = (in+1)%MAXIMUM;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  sem_post(&full);
}

void remove_item(int p){
  sem_wait(&full);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  int item = buffer[out];

  buffer[out]=0;
  printf("Consumer %d: Remove Item %d from %d\n",p,item, out);
   for(int i=0;i<MAXIMUM;i++) {
    printf("%d  ",buffer[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  out = (out+1)%MAXIMUM;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  sem_post(&empty);
}

void *producer() {
  for(int i=1001;i<=1010;i++){
     insert_item(i);
     int num = (rand() %
           (max_time - lower_time + 1)) + lower_time;

     sleep(num);
  }

  printf("----Producer exiting------");
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void *consumer( void *cno) {  
int p=*((int *)cno);

   for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
     int num = (rand() %
           (max_time - lower_time + 1)) + lower_time;
     sleep(num);
     remove_item(p);
   }

   pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to debug your own code. For example, where is each thread "stuck" on? This and other basic debug info can be found by running your program in a debugger. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Your producer produces 10 items.  *Each* of your consumers tries to consume 10 items.  If you have more than one consumer, then some of them will forever wait for items that will never be produced.

Comment: ok i got it @JohnBollinger

Comment: ty for your help guys @kaylum